# PHP- auto refresh page did not work

Tags: php, jquery, dreamweaver

i need a page to constantly refresh automatically. the refresh code is in display.php file. it work fine when i run the file on browser. but it did not refresh at all when i open it when click a button through file list.php. does my code have any problem?? or the code have a condition to make it work?

list.php

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="display.php">Taman</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

display.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv=refresh content="1; url=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
```

Comment: By saying through list.php, is it an iframe or what?

Comment: i dont know what if iframe is, but i dont think so. it's just a simple page to navigate to different page.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata can be used by browsers (how to display content or reload page), search engines (keywords), or other web services.

if you are just refreshing then no need to use php for url. just use for meta tag. 
Here the page will be reloaded on every 30 seconds

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

hope this will help you.

```
Tips and Notes
Note: <meta> tags always goes inside the <head> element.

Note: Metadata is always passed as name/value pairs.

Note: The content attribute MUST be defined if the name or the http-equiv attribute is defined. If none of these are defined, the content attribute CANNOT be defined.
```

Comment: tried. still the same. it did not refresh automatically when i enter the page from list.php. why is thi shappening?

Answer (score -1):

can you try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="refresh" content="30; url=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
```

Comment: Thats going to be a lot of refreshing!

Comment: why it will be creating a lot of refreshing ? i tried it on my system and it is working fine.

Comment: `content="0` = refreshes immediately

Comment: ok. thanks for that. but actually the page will be refreshed. am i right ?

Comment: no. . its not working. i still need to refreah the page manually once before it refresh automatically.